# Python Selenium get all elements in page source. driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to get all HTML tags in page_source by using the below code

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")
```

Most of the time it works as expected but for some rear cases (probably in bigger page_sources) it hangs and rises below the exception

```
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this or another equivalent command to get all HTML elements in page_source?
Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
Some elements are deleted by JS after the page is fully loaded. the solution is to add a try/except block whenever looping through each element as it might be deleted after the page is fully loaded. I hope this makes sense.